# Alternatives for doing backreferences in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a scenario where I need to match a pattern like with repeated numbers (41xx) where value of x will be same. For example, (4122, 4133, 4155, etc). I can do it using backreferences like '44([0-9]/1)'. But as backreferences are not supported on MySql is there any other way of achieving the same result?

Update:
What I tried

```
select '4455' regexp '44([0-9]/1)'
```

but as mysql doesn't seem to support backreferences so this query didn't give me results I expected.

Other alternative will be something like:

```
select '4455' regexp '44[0-9][0-9]'
```

but this will also match 4456, 4468, etc. I want to match the same pattern which means that I want to set the expectation that both the third and fourth digit are same.

Comment: can you post the SQL?

Comment: Why not `41[0-9][0-9]`?

Comment: If it's always the same digits you could try something like `SELECT c, IF(4400 + 11 * (c % 10) = c, 'T', 'F') result FROM (SELECT '4455' AS c UNION SELECT '4451' UNION SELECT '4411') b`